# Card flipping effect using CSS with flexible size.

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use the card flipping effect in this [blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) for a project I am working on. However, I cannot used fixed values for the width and height of the cards, because I need to account for different screen sizes.

Here is the code in the post:

```
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

This is an example of what I want to achieve.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the flip-card to be responsive so it will manage its affects on all screens without breaking. 
To do this, you need to use the percent rather than pixels measurements on width.

So using `width: 100%;` will change the layout to 100% of that element based on each screen resolution.

This is one approach, and it's the fastest and easiest one.

To do it, you only need to add another container to the `.flip-container` that will contain each row. Then you change the `.flip-container` position to `relative`. Now, you need to change the width of `.flip-container, .front, .back` selector to 100%. This way, the new container will handle the width of the full row.

here is an example :

```css
.card-container{
    width: 100%; /* Adjust the target width*/
}
.flip-container {
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000px;

}

    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.9s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
      background: #00ccff;

    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="card-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="flip-container">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="inner">Front</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">Back</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you still want to use fixed width and height measurements (e.g. px). You can always use [@media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and adjust the measurements or the overall style based on each rule.

Let's say the element is breaking on small screen resolutions. All you need to do is just add a rule for that. 
Example :

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
/* Your Style Here */

}
```

The above rule will be applied whenever the screen width is less than or equal to 800px. So, you can use `max-width` and `min-width` to change the style measurements based on the screen width of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a bit on this. I'm using javascript to set an active class, but you can probably use :active/:focus. Here a SASS example, and a [live example](http://julian-printemps.com/)

```
.flip {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;

  .active & {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  &--holder {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  // Container
  &--container {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;

    .active & {
      z-index: 100;
    }
  }
  // Container end


  // face
  &--face {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: $color-grey;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    color: #f0f0f0;

    &.front {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      &:hover {
        background-color: $color-grey-darker;
      }

      .active & {
          background-image: none;
          background-color: $color-white;
          -webkit-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) background-color;
          -moz-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) background-color;
          -ms-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) background-color;
          -o-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) background-color;
          transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) background-color;
      }
    }

    &.back {
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);

        padding: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: $color-white;
        color: $color-gray;
        fill: $color-gray;
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: $color-grey-lighter;
    }
  }
```

And a HTML snippet:

```
<div class="flip--container">
  <article class="flip">
    <div class="front flip--face">
      <div class="flip--icon--holder">
        <i class="flip--icon fa fa-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="back flip--face">
      <h3 class="flip--title">Title</h3>
      <ul class="flip--list">
        <li class="flip--list--item">Lorem</li>
        <li class="flip--list--item">Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but I was messing around this with issue and was able to find a pretty good solution (or at least I thought so) for a responsive flip card with images. This may need to be tweaked a bit if you're not using images, but it should be a good start. Hopefully, it will help someone else out!

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d6auxzef/4/

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/600/000033?text=FRONT" alt="Front" />
      </div>
      <div class="back">
         <img src="https://placehold.it/600/3300aa?text=BACK" alt="Back" />
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .outer {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: blue;
    }

    .flip-container {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }

    .flip-container:hover .flipper {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .front,
    .back {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .flipper {
      position: relative;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: .6s;
    }

    .front,
    .back {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      display: block;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .front > img, .back >img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .front {
      z-index: 2;
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    .back {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
</style>
```